# MDRoundFlatIconButton loses the background colour when it is enabled after disabling. Any fixes?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

In .kv file:

```
MDRoundFlatIconButton:
    icon: 'send-check'
    text: "Confirm"
    size_hint: .15, 1
    md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    on_release: app.submitSliderValue()
    disabled: not app.slider_active_bool
```

In .py file:

```
class BlackjackApp(MDApp):
    
    slider_active_bool = BooleanProperty(True)

    def initalize(self):
        sleep(1)
        self.slider_active_bool = False
        sleep(1)
        self.slider_active_bool = True
```

When the program starts, the button has the md_bg_color. After it is disabled, it behaves normally by greying out (like it should when disabled). But when it is re-enabled again, it does not get the same black colour as before. Help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a bug in `kivyMD`. You can work around it by adding an `on_disabled()` to your `kv`:

```
MDRoundFlatIconButton:
    icon: 'send-check'
    text: "Confirm"
    size_hint: .15, 1
    md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    on_release: app.submitSliderValue()
    disabled: not app.slider_active_bool
    on_disabled: app.butt_disabled(self)
```

Then add the `butt_disabled()` method to the `App`:

```
class BlackjackApp(MDApp):
    slider_active_bool = BooleanProperty(True)

    def butt_disabled(self, butt):
        if not butt.disabled:
            butt.md_bg_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)  # reset md_bg_color
```